# ReactJS - How can I set a value for textfield from material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a selectField and I want to set a value on it. Let say I type on it and when I click a button, the button will call a function that will reset the value of the textfield?

```
<TextField hintText="Enter Name" floatingLabelText="Client Name" autoWidth={1} ref='name'/>
```

Comment: Add the value to the TextField with state. Create a button, on button click call setState and change the value

Comment: fwiw, I had been using defaultValue instead of value, which was causing the TextField not to update when the value was changed externally (via another function outside of TextField)

Comment: Strange, none of the below solutions worked for me (React 18.2), but the defaultValue actually worked for me!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can do it in this way

```
export default class MyCustomeField extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          value: 'Enter text',
        };
      }

      handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
          value: event.target.value,
        });
      };

     handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({
          value:'',
        });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <TextField
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Reset Text</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: When I use "value" and "onChange" props simultaneously I get this warning:
"Warning: TextField is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https:// fb.me/react-controlled-components"

Comment: @WebBrother It may be the case that this.state.value is undefined. this.state.value should return the empty string instead of undefined if you do not want to supply some value.

Comment: @WebBrother you can avoid that warning by making it `value={this.state.value || ''}`

Comment: The update is much too slow, fast typing does not feel good with that solution.

Comment: -1. This is a very bad answer. The text field state is owned by text field element! You should not duplicate it in the main element - this is a very bad design and causes issues above. Instead use inputRef={this.textFieldRef). Now the text content is under this.textFieldRef.current.value, you can set and read it as you wish.

Answer (score 6):

It's maintained that the right way is to have the component be controlled in a scenario like the accepted answer there, but you can also control the value in this gross and culturally unacceptable way.

```
<TextField ref='name'/>

this.refs.name.getInputNode().value = 'some value, hooray'
```

and you can of course retrieve the value like so

```
this.refs.name.getValue()
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `ref` you should use `inputRef`

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  let input;

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(input.value);
      }}>
      <TextField
        hintText="Enter Name" 
        floatingLabelText="Client Name" 
        autoWidth={1}
        inputRef={node => {
          input = node;
        }}/>
    </form>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a short simple React Hook version of the answer

```
export default function MyCustomeField({
  initialValue= '', 
  placeholder= 'Enter your text...'
}) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue)

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setValue(initialValue)}>Reset Text</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to do a little wrap on the original MUI TextField.

```
export default function ValueTextField(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);
  return (
    <TextField {...props} onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)} value={value}/>
  );
}
```

Now you can use your own ValueTextField component now.

```
        <ValueTextField value={"hello world"}></ValueTextField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way to assign the state variables:

```
<TextField value={mobileNumber} 
     onChange={e => { this.setState({ mobileNumber: e.target.value }) }}
     className={classes.root}
     fullWidth={true}
     label={t('mobile number')} />
```